# Creating an encryption program in C++ by only using arrays. Not sure how to continue

Tags: c++

EDIT NOTE* I am not trying to create something to use. I am creating this to get a firm grasp on how arrays work in c++.

Hello I am creating a simple encryption program. This is my first program (for fun) and I am a bit confused on how to go on with this.(I have some code, but boy am I stuck!)

So, first of all, I am going to use the ROT-N encryption method.

Basically I want the user to enter a message, and have the message obey these rules:

1)  Shift every character/digit the user enters and shift it to the right 8-15 characters/digits, and have it loop around. I do not want to go into the extended characters list.

2) If the user enters a lowercase letter, I want to make it become lowercase.

3) Last bit - I want the spaces to be encrypted too. The program should point out where the spaces are.

Ex. If user enters "Message 0600"

The encrypted message should say "8umaaiom3933&8"

The "8" in the beginning says how much the letters are offset. The "umaaiom3933" is the encrypted message. The & signifies that the message is over, and the last "8" signifies where the space is.

What I am having trouble with:

1)Trying to take the message from the user and putting it in a array (each character in the message becomes a character in the array)

2) Taking those characters and adding the offset value for a different value

This is what I have so far.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    int n = 13;
    cout << n << endl;
    int r = n + 255;
    string mes, emes;
    cout << "Please enter the message: " << endl;
    getline(cin,mes);
    int len = mes.length();
    for(int i = 0; i <= len; i++)
    {
        mes[i] += n;
    }
    cout << mes;





    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't assign a `std::string` to an array (definitely not like that), you'd have to copy it (e.g.: using `strncpy`). However you can also simply iterate over the contents of `std::string`, there is no need to explicitly copy it to a `char` array.

Comment: Shuffling characters in the alphabet is both ineffective and complicated, why don't you use the good old [xor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or)? You can make real good encryption being a little inventive with that.

Comment: Also, `rmes = message` is missing the `;`, and I don't think copying a `std::string` to a `char[1000]` that way is safe or legal. Use `strcpy_s(rmes, 1000, message.c_str());`. or drop the memory redundancy and use pointers `char *rmes = message.c_str();`.

Comment: Sorry I do not know how to use xor. I put a semi colon. Thanks for reminding me!

Comment: Xor is a bitwise operation that does `0^0=0`, `1^1=0` and anything else `=1`. If you do iterate each character with `y = x^123` for instance you generate a string that can't be read, if you pass that through the same algorithm again it reverts to the original string. It's very simple.

Comment: Instead of using the 'string message' to get the message, how would I just put the message from the user into the array? Spaces and all.

Comment: With `cin.getline(rmes, 1000);`. Since it's an array the library requires you to specify the size to avoid buffer overflow.

Comment: ["Schneier's Law"](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2011/04/schneiers_law.html): Anyone, from the most clueless amateur to the best cryptographer, can create an algorithm that he himself can't break.

Comment: If you want encryption use AES (Advanced Encryption Standard). Whay you have is basicallyjust encoding, there is no secret key.

Comment: This program is only so I can grasp how to use arrays properly. I have changed the code a bit to fit what I am trying to do. Sorry if I am not able to clearly articulate what I am trying to do with this program.

Answer (score 0):

Basically a C string is a plain region of memory with the format

'H' 'e' 'l' 'l' 'o' '-' 'w' 'o' 'r' 'l' 'd' 0

So assuming we have a function char encrypt(char ch), which encrypts a char.

```
int i;
char *str; /* the input string */

for(i=0;str[i] != 0; i++)
  str[i] = encrypt(str[i]);
```

However C++ standard template library strings are a bit different. They have far more machinery attached. Whilst you can try to modify them in place, really you're better off getting into the habit of thinking of them as immutable and constant. However you can build one with push_back.

So

```
std::string encryptstring(const std::string &plaintext)
{
   size_t i;  // should be int or index_t, very poor choice of name by the C++ folks
   std::string answer;

    for(i=0;i<plaintext.length();i++)
    {
        answer.push_back( encrypt(plaintext[i]));
    }

    return answer;
}
```

That's the idiomatic way of doing it. C++ does allow direct access to string contents, but it tends to discourage it.

Comment: Thank you! This helps a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I read all of your comments. They were very helpful, thanks! I actually took the time to think and research. I was able to finish the program. Here it is!

The biggest problem that I had was that I did not understand that in c++ a string writes directly to a character array

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main()

{
    srand(time(0));

    string imes, omes;
    int len;
    int n = rand()%(15 - 8 + 1) + 8;

    cout << "Please Enter a Message:  " << endl;
    getline (cin, imes);    
    std::ostringstream oss;
    len = imes.length();

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        imes[i] = tolower(imes[i]);
        if (imes[i] >= 'a' && imes[i] <= 'z')
        {
            omes += ((imes[i] - 'a' + n) % 26) + 'a';
        }
        if (imes[i] >= '0' && imes[i] <= '9')
        {
            omes += ((imes[i] - '0' + n) % 10) + '0';
        }   
        else 

        if(imes[i] == ' ')
        { 
            if (imes[i - 1] >= 'a' && imes[i - 1] <= 'z')
            {
                omes += ((imes[i - 1] - 'a' + 4) % 26) + 'a';
            }
            else
            if (imes[i - 1] >= '0' && imes[i - 1] <= '9')
            {
                omes += ((imes[i - 1] - '0' + 4) % 10) + '0';
            }
            oss << '#' << i;
        }
    }

    omes << '&' << oss.str() << endl;
    cout << "The message has been encrypted and transmitted" << endl;
    outdata.close();
    return 0;
}
```